# How to fix this crash issue that happens randomly when I explore the world?

Tags: azerothcore

I found this in the crash log? not sure what to do or how to fix it? I'm not sure how to share my crash file...

Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION
Fault address:  00007FF6FD78E7E2 01:00000000001CD7E2 C:\build\bin\RelWithDebInfo\worldserver.exe

Answer (score 1):

For a crash, you should generally open a bug report over at the AzerothCore repository.

As for sharing a crash file, you will first have to have your build in `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo` as a crash file in `Release` is useless and unreadable.

In your case, you will be able to find the crash log in the `C:\build\bin\RelWithDebInfo\Crashes\` folder.

And to share it you can copy the contents of the text file into a PasteBin or gist.github.com and then share it that way.